# Problemas WSDL ABAP & PHP

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, sap, abap

queria ver si alguien me puede ayudar ya que estoy teniendo problemas para enviar parametros mediante php y SWDL a SAP tengo la siguiente estructura

```
$result = $client->call($rfc,array($tabla =>
        array(
            "IFechaFin" => "20230111", 
            "IFechaIni" => "20230101"
        )
    )
,$wsdl);
```

si llega a SAP y todo pero al momento de consultar las variables I_FECHA_INI y I_FECHA_FIN siempre me llegan vacias, agradeceria si me pudieran ayudar y asi esta la estructura

```
<xsd:sequence><xsd:element name="IFechaFin" type="n0:string" minOccurs="0"/><xsd:element name="IFechaIni" type="n0:string" minOccurs="0"/><xsd:element name="TabFacturas" type="tns:TableOfZdtRepFacturas"/></xsd:sequence>
```